# Pascal's triangle not working in Python 3

Tags: python

I am new to Python. Can somebody explain please why is this code not populating the 2D array as Pascal's triangle?

```
def PascalTri(n):
    ar=[[0]*n]*n
    print(ar)
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,i+1):
            if j==0 or i==j:
                ar[i][j]=1
            else:
                ar[i][j]=ar[i-1][j-1] + ar[i-1][j]

    print(ar)

PascalTri(5)
```

Output :

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 4, 8, 9, 1], [1, 4, 8, 9, 1], [1, 4, 8, 9, 1], [1, 4, 8, 9, 1], [1, 4, 8, 9, 1]]
```

Comment: tl;dr `ar = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: `ar=[[0]*n]*n` doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: Thanks Sir. I think I got the idea. I thought it will create a 2D array and initialize it with zeros. But that isn't the case. I will read more regarding it. @Code-Apprentice